# Битрикс. Почему игнорируется сложная фильтрация?

Tags: php, битрикс

Битрикс. Получаем секции инфоблоков. В инфоблоках имеются (в т.ч.) два свойства "Акции" и "Новинки", которые являются типом "Справочник", которые (справочники) в свою очередь - это highload-блоки.

Не работает такой фильтр (точнее работает, но игнорируется блок с `"PROPERTY"`):

```
    $arFilter = array(
        "IBLOCK_ID"=>$arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "GLOBAL_ACTIVE"=>"Y",
        "IBLOCK_ACTIVE"=>"Y",
        "<="."DEPTH_LEVEL" => $arParams["DEPTH_LEVEL"],
        "CNT_ACTIVE" => "Y",
        "PROPERTY" => array(
            array(
                "LOGIC" => "OR",
                array(">AKTSIYA"=>"2"),
                array("NOVINKA"=>"3a776810"),
            )
        ),
    );
```

При этой выборке:

```
    $arOrder = array(
        "left_margin"=>"asc",
    );

    $rsSections = CIBlockSection::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, true, array(
        "ID",
        "DEPTH_LEVEL",
        "NAME",
        "SECTION_PAGE_URL",
    ));
```

Причем если фильтровать отдельно по каждому элементу, то все работает:

```
    $arFilter = array(
        "IBLOCK_ID"=>$arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "GLOBAL_ACTIVE"=>"Y",
        "IBLOCK_ACTIVE"=>"Y",
        "<="."DEPTH_LEVEL" => $arParams["DEPTH_LEVEL"],
        "CNT_ACTIVE" => "Y",
        "PROPERTY" => array(">AKTSIYA"=>"2")
    );
```

и

```
    $arFilter = array(
        "IBLOCK_ID"=>$arParams["IBLOCK_ID"],
        "GLOBAL_ACTIVE"=>"Y",
        "IBLOCK_ACTIVE"=>"Y",
        "<="."DEPTH_LEVEL" => $arParams["DEPTH_LEVEL"],
        "CNT_ACTIVE" => "Y",
        "PROPERTY" => array("NOVINKA"=>"3a776810")
    );
```

В первом фильтре со сложным запросом если вывести SQL-запросы на страницу, то по всему коду страницы фраза "3a776810" отсутствует. Значит получается, что этот фильтр с логикой не попадает в SQL-запрос. Почему?

Comment: Возможно `"LOGIC" => "OR"` не поддерживается для категорий. Сделай простой фильтр **И** по обоим пропертям и проверь.

Comment: Да нет, поддерживается

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$arrFilter[] = array( 
   "LOGIC" => "OR", 
        array(">PROPERTY_AKTSIYA" => "2"), 
        array("=PROPERTY_NOVINKA" => "3a776810") 
);
```